# Slow download speed but high surfing speed

Tags: downloads

I have been using Ubuntu 10 since last many months and for the first time since last few days, the Downloading speed has reduced to 15 kbps instead of standard 150 kbps.

But My Surfing speed and installation/update speed are pretty much fine.

Its only when i use torrent download I am facing such problem.

Tata Photon Plus
Avg. D/L Speed as per plan 3.1 mbds actual 1.9 mbps 
At present speed 15 kbps!!!! but normal surfing speed.

Hence please let me know how can i again equal the downloading speed to that of surfing speed.......

Comment: Several providers reduce the bandwidth for torrent connections. Maybe this happened in your case.

Comment: Are you using Transmission? I have this same problem. Even if it is only downloading at 5kb, it will slow the internet to a crawl.

Comment: Photon Throttles Torrent connections

Answer (score 4):

As someone who works within the ISP industry I can confirm this is likely due to the fact you are downloading torrents.

For example, by using Deep Packet Inspection we can discover and then implement traffic shaping on particular types of transit.

This will mean that your general internet surfing will be fine - whereas torrents etc will suffer from capped/shaped speeds.